# Moving to new domain and site

Tags: redirects, web-hosting, dns, 301-redirect, godaddy

I have an old web site `www.domain1.example` (IP: `x1.x1.x1.x1`) hosted on GoDaddy and created a new one with new domain `www.domain2.example` (IP: `x2.x2.x2.x2`) hosted on Hostinger. Both domains purchased from local domain reseller. `domain1.example` managed at GoDaddy and I am using their Office 365 for mails. So I don't want to transfer old domain to new provider.
Now I want to retire an old site and redirect all customers to new site.

I changed @ A record and pointed `domain1.example` to `x2.x2.x2.x2` and getting `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. So I changed it back.
Meanwhile I make redirection with `.htaccess` file. But I would like to get rid off old hosting?

What is a best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit difficult to answer your question, but I think it the issue is likely with your SSL Certificate.

SSL Certificates have the names of all the domains they are associated in them.  If you want the website associated with domain2.example to come up when you enter domain1.example, in addition to doing redirection in DNS you need to generate a new certificate which includes both domains.  (So this is likely the more correct solution - change the DNS1 to point back to the IP for domain2.example, make sure the VHOST answers for domain2.example as well as domain1.example and generate a certificate covering both domains)

How you handle this depends on your goals, but I do wonder if you could get away with simply setting up 301 redirects for everything on domain1.example to domain2.example, and then just ditching domain1.example for web hosting after a few months.